# Why on earth am I getting unfilled space between the edge of my shape and the fill of the same shape?

Tags: java, android, graphics

As part of an Android Wear watch face I started putting together, I have a class which implements rendering for one hand of a watch. It looks like this (after I edited out the bits which aren't relevant):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;

class Hand {
    private final float centerX;
    private final float centerY;

    private final Path untransformedPath;
    private final Path path = new Path();

    private final Paint fillPaint;

    private final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    Hand2(Context context,
          int widthId, int fillColorId, int strokeWidthId,
          float centerX, float centerY, float handLength) {

        this.centerX = centerX;
        this.centerY = centerY;

        float halfHandWidth = context.getResources().getDimension(widthId) / 2;

        int fillColor = Workarounds.getColor(context, fillColorId);

        fillPaint = new Paint();
        fillPaint.setColor(fillColor);
        fillPaint.setStrokeWidth(context.getResources().getDimension(strokeWidthId));
        fillPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);
        fillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        fillPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        untransformedPath = new Path();

        float centreRadius = context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.analog_centre_hand_start_radius);
        float centreDegrees = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(halfHandWidth / centreRadius));
        float startOffset = (float) Math.sqrt(centreRadius * centreRadius - halfHandWidth * halfHandWidth);
        float centreStartDegrees = 90.0f - centreDegrees;
        float centreSweepDegrees = 2.0f * centreDegrees;

        untransformedPath.moveTo(-halfHandWidth, startOffset);
        untransformedPath.lineTo(-halfHandWidth, handLength - halfHandWidth);
        untransformedPath.lineTo(0, handLength);
        untransformedPath.lineTo(halfHandWidth, handLength - halfHandWidth);
        untransformedPath.lineTo(halfHandWidth, startOffset);
        untransformedPath.arcTo(
                -centreRadius, -centreRadius, centreRadius, centreRadius,
                centreStartDegrees, centreSweepDegrees, false);
        untransformedPath.close();
    }

    void updateAngle(float angleDegrees) {
        matrix.reset();
        matrix.setRotate(angleDegrees, 0, 0);
        matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);

        untransformedPath.transform(matrix, path);
    }

    Path getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, fillPaint);
    }

    void updateHighQuality(boolean highQuality) {
        fillPaint.setAntiAlias(highQuality);
    }
}
```

I had noticed the rendering appeared to flicker for some reason and no amount of double buffering appeared to solve it. So I did a crazy thing and hit screenshot many times in a row and eventually caught a screenshot of what's going on:

[image]

You can see something like a black line going around one of the hands. If you look carefully, it isn't actually a black line, but rather, it's as if there is a gap in what got filled which is right next to the border of the shape.

What exactly is going on here? I'm rendering a single shape which is `FILL_AND_STROKE`, so it seems kind of crazy that it would somehow be leaving any of that shape unpainted. And yet, that is exactly what it appears to be doing.

If you're wondering about the glow painted below the hands, that is a separate thing rendered on the background by another class before the hands are drawn, which is why you don't see me doing that here. (The `getPath()` method is the way which that other class grabs the current path so that it knows where to put the glow.)

Further investigation:

- Reversing the order of the vertices in the path has no effect.
- Removing the curve in the path does appear to stop whatever is happening, interestingly.
- Filling and stroking separately using exactly the same settings also appears to stop it happening.

Comment: I may be imagining it, but it seems like every time I see this happening, the hand is somewhere near the text view showing the date...

Comment: Did you check your logs to see if it is unhappy with something?

Comment: @zgc7009 the logs as always are too flooded with pointless messages to be useful, but I can't see anything that looks like an error I haven't already seen before.